# Is http://www.stackfullow.com/ a phishing site?

Tags: discussion, phishing

I just accidentally stumbled on this site from Google. I was wondering if there is anything that can be done to prevent phishing from such a site?

Comment: Please don't down vote me. I mean let me know if its not a good question to ask. My intention is to just share this information and to see if anything that can be done against such sites. I would have accidently just keyed in my password there had I not been careful enough.

Comment: As you may or may not know, voting on Meta tends to indicate agreement or disagreement rather than question or answer quality.

Comment: Right, here its targetted to stackoverflow.com specifically.

Comment: Is it a phishing site, or just a [meta-tag:copycat-sites]?  I didn't visit it.

Comment: @ryanyuyu A full copycat site but the login links are all directing back to `http://stackoverflow.com`

Comment: Funnily enough after clicking on one link I got stopped by a captcha page that didn't seem to have an actual captcha on it... I guess I'm a robot and didn't realize it.

Comment: I downvote these because all they do is draw more attention to the sites (and possibly provide pagerank when there's an actual clickable link).  There's absolutely nothing Meta can do about them.  Follow the standard procedure and contact the SO team.

Comment: We only made approx 83 hits as of now :) though I understand what you mean. I was trying to understand if anything can be done like say some copyright claims etc can be filed.

Comment: it's a redirect to an imgur thing now